# Sem tradução no fim da mensagem de ganhar uma medalha

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Ao ganhar uma medalha, fui ver a mensagem e esta faltando traduzir o final dela.

> Você ganhou uma medalha "Escolar" < titulo da pergunta > . See your profile.

Deveria ficar

> Você ganhou uma medalha "Escolar" < titulo da pergunta > . Veja seu perfil.

[image: print do bug]

Comment: @Gabe Ainda tem [um bugzinho](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1985/ajuste-na-tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-notifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-medalha) na notificação.